# Problem using regex to adjust query strings in htaccess redirectmatch

Tags: .htaccess

There's income traffic to my website with a pattern like this:

```
/index.php?title=xxx&somethingelse=yyy
```

And I need to turn it into this pattern:

```
/somefolder/xxx/
```

I've tried different things, such as:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php\?title=([^&]*).*$ https://example.com/somefolder/$1/
```

The above code, and many other alternatives that I've tried based on online posts and articles didn't work. Maybe I'm just making a silly mistake somewhere; it's been half a day that I'm trying without success!

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure that you took a look into the documentation of the tool you are using? Because it seems you completely missed the point mentioned in there and in all answers here which explains that the query string is _not_ part of the URL. You cannot match it like that.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=([^&]*)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ https://example.com/somefolder/%1/ [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?somefolder/(.+)/?$ https://example.com/index.php?title=$1 [END,QSA]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, as well as the tips on using 302 to test the rules and to optimize htaccess rules in general; I've never thought of that.

Comment: I don't understand the last line of code though; what does it do?

Comment: The code shows the usual two step approach: the first step, the combination of condition and rule, externally redirects the ugly to the clean URL. The second step internally rewrites incoming clean URLs to the internally required format that can be processed by your php based application.